# Como publicar um projeto em ASP.NET MVC em uma URL especifica

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

Então, estou em uma situação que não sei como e nem sei se é possível fazer.

Tenho um site em ASP.NET MVC, vamos chama-lo de *sitedokelvin.com.br*, este site é um projeto asp.net mvc.

E também tenho um outro site, vamos chama-lo de *projetodokelvin.com.br*, este site é um outro projeto aspnet mvc.

O que eu queria fazer é publicar o site *projetodokelvin.com.br* dentro do projeto *sitedokelvin.com.br* sem precisar mesclar os projetos no mesmo projeto do visual studio, queria que os dois ficassem separados dentro da mesma *solution*.

Assim a [url](/questions/tagged/url) ficaria:

http://sitedokelvin.com.br/projetodokelvin

Tem como fazer isso? Qual é o nome disso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri pela comunidade MSDN que devo utilizar o Diretórios virtuais ([Link MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/918d4ea1-1bce-498a-9d5a-1f96c1504297/how-to-publish-an-aspnet-mvc-4-project-in-a-specific-url-on-windows-azure?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview))
Porém, encontrei o como implementar esta questão, pela comunidade do StackOverflow ([Link para a solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341616/publish-multiple-projects-to-different-locations-on-azure-website/21346077#21346077)).

Lembrando que estou utilizando o Windows Azure Web Sites. Essa configuração é do IIS mas este link da solução que mandei é especificamente para o Azure.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Usando áreas. [Tem esse tutorial da Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) e mais alguns outros pela internet. Não vale a pena colocar um passo a passo como resposta por causa do tamanho.

Comment: Oi Cigano, infelizmente não é isso que estou precisando. Eu pesquisei e o pessoal da comunidade da MSDN acabou me respondendo. O que precisei utilizar foi virtual folders. Com isso eu posso publicar diferentes aplicações em determinadas URLs. Valeu!